# Total number of solutions...

Tags: permutations, systems-of-equations, combinations

The equation given to solve is 
**w+2x+5y+10z=N**
How can I find the total number of integral solutions of this equation provided that **(w>0,x>0,y>0,z>0)**.
Given that N is a fixed natural number that can be plugged into the equation.. w,x,y,z are integral values only....

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any details missing in the description? Because like that, this equation will have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @wet only this is given in the problem...

Comment: @wet Integer solutions....

Comment: Is it FrobeniusSolve problem?

Comment: Positive integer solutions, no? "Provided that $w, x, y, z > 0$", still infinitely many solutions. E.g. $N=18$, then one solution, $(1,1,1,1)$, $N=19$ another solution, $N=28$ will have ten solutions I guess.

Comment: Is $N$ natural?